# infections too great in number (or kids in kindergardens)

Tags: infectious-diseases, pediatrics

The media is full of pediatric recommendation "be sick viral infections 12 times per year is normal", even "16 times per year is normal".

For example first google suggestion:
[The constant cold: Why kids are always sick and what to do about it](https://mcpress.mayoclinic.org/parenting/the-constant-cold-why-kids-are-always-sick-and-what-to-do-about-it/)

> A: It varies a lot among kids. But most babies, toddlers and
> preschoolers can have as many as 12 colds a year and still be normal.
> On average, you’ll probably see between seven and eight infections a
> year. This number may be higher for children who are attending day
> care or when they start attending school.

Is there any research that put some sense to this?

How do they make that out?
How it is possible to split "12-16 times per year" into episodes?

What is "normal" here? 80% kids without complications? After 1 year or after 3 such years? 3rd level of adenoid hypertrophy is still normal? 2nd? No logopedic problems? No learning problems?

Usually we impose that those numbers are related to kids on day care. But what about quality of that day care?

Any kind of conditions? third month - 3rd times with antibiotics is still "normal"? high temperature stay for a week also counts? or week on pyretic?

Imagine there are two type of kindergarden groups: first is where parents and administration are responsible and second is... usual ("we pay, we should work"). If parents visit hospital with the question "why my child is sick every 2 weeks" should we first ask about the environment? may be some groups are really dangerous?

How the generic recommendation "12 is normal" can exists without questioning the quality of the day care? What kind of quality could be if parents know only that beeing sick is normal and are not interested in all other details?

P.S. I have found this article ["Approach to the child with recurrent infections"](https://www.uptodate.com/contents/approach-to-the-child-with-recurrent-infections/print#:%7E:text=Recurrent%20infections%20are%20infections%20that,antibiotics%20for%20two%20months%2Fyear.) where they tries to classify some situations, but still there are no such class for "it is recurrent just because of too many infections around your kid and because you do not give him time to recovery".

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152230/discussion-on-question-by-roman-pokrovskij-infections-too-great-in-number-or-ki); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.